# How do I make a block appear in a panels display based on the state of a field

Tags: 7, theming, entities, panels

I have a field that is a single on/off checkbox. Whenever it has been selected it outputs a key of 1 into the panel display, if it hasn't it outputs a 0. I want it to output custom html for a link to another page if it's a 1 and I want it to become disabled/hidden if it's 0. The resulting block/field/html needs to be inputted into a panels display, just like the key currently does.

As of right now, I'm using jquery to do this for me, but it seems like there HAS to be a way to do this with drupal. I've looked into  conditional_fields and field_conditional_state but they seemed to be more focused on entering conditional information and not on only making conditional outputs. I'm currently looking into minipanels, panel pages, and context right now to figure this out, but haven't found an easy way of doing it and it feels like I'm overthinking it.

I know that there's a States API that handles this kind of thing, but there's surprisingly little information that I've been able to find on how to apply it to displays. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Cole

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your case you could :
 - have a [Static field](https://www.drupal.org/project/static_field), containing your link
 - use [Conditional Fields Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) and set up a condition with :

"dependee"  = your checkbox
"dependent" = your static field (containing your link to another page)
condition = dependent is visible if dependee has value 1